# Hybrid mobile app with cordova working in cordova sim but not when exported as android apk

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app

I am working on a hybrid mobile application which was easy to make.. fine.. but it dosent work on an actual android  sim or device.

Below is my setup.

IDE: Jboss dev studio
jdk: 1.8
tools in path: android, ant, git, node

i created a hybrid mobile app in jboss dev tools with hybrid mobile engine as cordova 4.1.1. Below is the project structure.

[project structure and config.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TuXOd.png)

Im also copy pasting the config below.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.nexisone" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>nexisone</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the
        deviceready
        event.
    </description>
    <author href="http://www.eclipse.org/thym" email="thym-dev@eclipse.org">
        Eclipse.org -
        Thym
    </author>

    <content src="mobileapp.html" /><!-- "index.html" -->
    <!-- Whitelist configuration. Refer to https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html -->
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />

    <access origin="*.*" subdomains="true"/>
    <!-- <access origin=".*" /> -->
    <!-- <access origin="http://127.0.0.1:9090" /> -->
    <access origin="http://192.168.71.125*" subdomains="true"/><!-- resource server ip -->
    <access origin="http://*.jquery.com*" subdomains="true"/>
    <access origin="http://ticketmonster-jdf.rhcloud.com"/>
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
    <engine name="android" version="4.1.1" />
    <feature name="Geolocation">
        <param name="id" value="cordova-plugin-geolocation" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Camera">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.camera.CameraLauncher" />
        <param name="wp-package" value="Camera" />
        <param name="id" value="cordova-plugin-camera" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Device">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.device.Device" />
        <param name="wp-package" value="Device" />
        <param name="id" value="cordova-plugin-device" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Notification">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.dialogs.Notification" />
        <param name="wp-package" value="Notification" />
        <param name="id" value="cordova-plugin-dialogs" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="StatusBar">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.statusbar.StatusBar" />
        <param name="onload" value="true" />
        <param name="wp-package" value="StatusBar" />
        <param name="id" value="cordova-plugin-statusbar" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Whitelist">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.whitelist.WhitelistPlugin" />
        <param name="onload" value="true" />
        <param name="id" value="cordova-plugin-whitelist" />
    </feature>
</widget>
```

and here is the mobileapp.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <title>jQuery Mobile Template</title> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
    <!-- Good default declaration:
    * gap: is required only on iOS (when using UIWebView) and is needed for JS->native communication
    * https://ssl.gstatic.com is required only on Android and is needed for TalkBack to function properly
    * Disables use of eval() and inline scripts in order to mitigate risk of XSS vulnerabilities. To change this:
        * Enable inline JS: add 'unsafe-inline' to default-src
        * Enable eval(): add 'unsafe-eval' to default-src
-->
<!-- <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *"> -->

<!-- Allow requests to foo.com -->
<!-- <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' jquery.com"> -->

<!-- Enable all requests, inline styles, and eval() -->
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; script-src 'self' * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">

<!-- Allow XHRs via https only -->
<!-- <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' https:"> -->

<!-- Allow iframe to https://cordova.apache.org/ -->
<!-- <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; frame-src 'self' https://cordova.apache.org"> -->
<!-- Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only: policy -->
<!--  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' *;media-src *;script-src *;style-src * ">  -->
<!-- <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com http://code.jquery.com http://192.168.71.125:9090; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' http://code.jquery.com; media-src *"> -->
    <meta name="viewport" 
        content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" /> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" 
        href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" /> 
    <script type="text/javascript" 
        src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" 
        src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript"> 

        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

        function onDeviceReady() {
              console.log("Device Ready To Go");
              console.log("Asking for geo location");
              navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onGeoSuccess, onGeoError);

            } // onDeviceReady

        $(document).on("pageinit", "#page1", function(event){ 
            console.log("Ready To Go"); 
        }); 
        $.support.cors = true;
         $.getJSON("http://192.168.71.125:9090", function(members) {
                // console.log("returned are " + members);
                var listOfMembers = $("#listOfItems");
                listOfMembers.empty();
                $.each(members, function(index, member) {
                       // console.log(member.name);
                      listOfMembers.append(
                        "<li><a href='#'>" + member.name + "</a>");
                });
                listOfMembers.listview("refresh");
            });
        function onGeoSuccess(position) {
               var element = document.getElementById('geolocation');
               element.innerHTML =
                'Latitude: '  + position.coords.latitude          + '<br />' +
                'Longitude: ' + position.coords.longitude         + '<br />' +
                'Altitude: '  + position.coords.altitude          + '<br />' +
                'Accuracy: '  + position.coords.accuracy          + '<br />' +
                'Alt Accuracy: ' + position.coords.altitudeAccuracy + '<br />' +
                'Heading: '   + position.coords.heading           + '<br />' +
                'Speed: '     + position.coords.speed             + '<br />' +
                'Timestamp: ' + position.timestamp                + '<br />';
             }
        function onGeoError(error) {
               alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
                     'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
        }
    </script> 
</head> 
<body> 
    <div data-role="page" id="page1"> 
        <div data-role="header"> 
            <h1>jQuery Mobile</h1> 
        </div> 
        <div data-role="content"> 
        <div id="geolocation">Finding geolocation...</div><p>
            <ul id="listOfItems" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" 
                data-filter="true"> 
                <li><a href="">One</a></li> 
                <li><a href="">Two</a></li> 
                <li><a href="">Three</a></li> 
            </ul> 
        </div> 
        <div data-role="footer"> 
            <h4>www.jboss.org/developer</h4> 
        </div> 
    </div> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Now it works on cordova sim, but when i export it as apk and run it on android simulator or android phone, it does not load jquery.

When i look at the app in chrome remote debugger, i get the below console output.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
mobileapp.html:50 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
mobileapp.html:44 Device Ready To Go
mobileapp.html:45 Asking for geo location
http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

I have tried to load cordova.js before everything else on the page but im not sure if i did it right. Also, here is how my exported android project looks. Please tell me if it is some config in android- manifest or cordova .. its driving me beans.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.nexisone">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>

    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="nexisone" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="22"/>

            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
        </manifest>
```

[Android project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPAkV.png)

Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: "but it dosent work on an actual android sim or device" What happens when you start the apk. When you say it doesnt work, what actually happens or precisely happens not?

Comment: the error messages in the chrome remote debugger console show the issue. Its not able to load jquery or anything from an external url. http://postimg.org/image/o6314n1d1/. in this image u see the cordova sim on the right and android emulator in left.

Comment: im also looking for someone to make a comment about how the configuration looks.. anything u might suggest is appreciated.

Comment: i suspect cordova.js is not loaded at the right time? what could be the right place for it?

Comment: Move All your script tags to the end of your document. Right before your </body> tag

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your Problem and how you could solve it on your own

1. Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
2. So check the URL in Browser, which is fine
3. So only your App cant reach the url
4. It cant be the Content-Security-Policy, the error then would be violation of Content-Security-Policy
5. So your Whitelist is not properly configured
6. Check https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist for the right syntax

Or in short form:
Add in config.xml

```
<access origin="http://code.jquery.com"/>
```